# terraform local & lookup help for azure

Tags: azure, terraform

Just a quick question to understand whats the best way to use this. To fetch values off "locals" in terraform do i use lookup(local.this) or local.this or example below i got:

```
 locals {
  array = {"this" = data.something.output, "this02" = data.something.output }
}
```

Comment: Your question is hard to follow as it is right now. Could you please edit it a little to be closer to an [mcve] such as making sure the content in your `testrule.tf` is a full resource definition? It might be helpful to show what the contents of `nsg.json` looks like too.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference each declaration within a locals block just as you would a normal variable, but as `local.name` instead of `var.name`.

So for your example you could use `lookup(local.array,"this","defaultvalue")`, or any of the other ways to access a map variable.